# Replace CentOS with Ubuntu on a remote server (SSH access only)

Tags: ubuntu, centos, partition, system-installation

I am trying to replace CentOS with Ubuntu Server on a remote machine where the only access is via network (SSH-only at present, VNC may be set up if needed). I have fully backed up all data on the server. Ideally the only running system will be Ubuntu Server after this is done.

To reduce risk, I have set up a CentOS server in a virtual machine running locally. Disk configuration is the same as remote: One boot partition, one LVM with a single XFS partition inside. The amount of computing resource is also the same: 2 CPU cores and 4 GiB RAM.

It's important to note that, while the setup process was done with "physical" access (it's a VM after all), it's intended to serve as a rehearsal platform, and therefore I must perform all other actions via SSH after the initial setup, which itself is not relevant.

I initially planned to install Ubuntu as dual-boot and remove CentOS afterwards, but some Google-ing beforehand told me that it's impossible to shrink the XFS partition, so I'm lost and don't know what to do now.

How can I replace the CentOS on the remote machine with Ubuntu Server, without losing SSH access?

Comment: Do you have access to the remote system's console? If not, what was the procedure used to install CentOS?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick The setup process is not relevant. I need to perform the OS replacement with only SSH access.

Comment: I don't think you can do this. Go to the web interface of your provider and initialize the Server with Ubuntu ... Or if that is not available, ask your provider what to do.

Comment: @RoVo Guess that's the only option for me. Thanks!

Comment: If you have a backup of your data, its not worth the trouble anyway.

Comment: @Bananguin The real problem is, the server is school-issued, and therefore asking for an exchange is extraordinarily troublesome.

Comment: @iBug then learn CentOS. It's not that big a deal